# How to improve UI in .Net Compact Framework, C#?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have some WinForms in my application.

On some form , I am loading other forms which have lot of data to show.

So when I click a button to load these forms they take, 9-10 seconds to load,

I wana improve this. I have heard about Background thread but don't know how to use this.

Means on the button click what should i do so that I can see my form imidiately and the processing is done by background thread ?

Please guide me so that I can improve my UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the form to show immediately, should be fairly simple and you don't need a background thread to do it.

My guess is that you are retrieving all that data prior to loading the form or you are retrieving the data on the same thread that loads the form.  You should be able to call the form with the data it needs to retrieve the rest of the data (such as ID's).

Then you just need to find a way for the data processing to happen on a thread other than the thread that creates the form.

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done.  It uses a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        //fill controls with data
    }
```

If you have several sets of data that you are retrieving, you may want to consider setting up a queue of tasks to retrieve each set.

Any way that you do it.  Make sure to disable any buttons(or other ui) that could cause errors if the data is not loaded.

Edit:  It should be noted that winform controls don't always play nice with threads.  The nice thing about the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (as opposed to `System.Timers.Timer`)is that it designed to play nice with controls.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker are easy to use. Mainly you subscribe to DoWork event, this is where you'd put your work that will be done in a seperate thread. And you also subscribe to RunWorkerCompleted event. This will get raised when your DoWork has completed. 
In this method you'd simply bind the data fetched by the DoWork method.

You can use the DoWork eventarg to pass data between DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted. 
You can also cancel the work and also the you can use the RunWorkerCompleted eventArg to get the data from the DoWork and also inspect the Error property for exception handling.

IF you have lots of data, you can use a batching process, to get data per batch and display them into your UI. You can show how many total records will be fetch and the progress of it 100 out of 1000 have been loaded, 200 out of 1000 have been loaded etc, to keep the user informed. You could also provide a Cancel option so the user can stop the fetch.

In your button click you'd simply call myBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync().
this will call your DoWork Handler which will be done in a seperate thread not the main UI Thread, so your UI will not FREEZE during the background worker DoWork.

The backgroundworker also support report progress.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the main form Freezing, what you need is to collect the data on a separated Thread than the Main form is running.

To achieve that, you can do something like this:

```
    BackgroundWorker worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Collect data and open your second form here;
    }
```